# The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to populate a Spinner with a JSON object that I am pulling from a restful API.

But I cannot figure out how to get Adapter working for the spinner. I have tried `getActivity()` and I've tried the `this` keyword. Neither one has worked and I can't find anything on Google where people are trying to update the spinner in this context.

Here is the code I am using. http://pastebin.com/bQWDHekB. When I just `getActivity()` it says, `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}`

but when I use `this` is says `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new Runnable(){}, int, String[]) is undefined`

-- EDIT --
As per Maartens' answer, I found that using `MainActivity.this` worked better than `getApplicationContext()`. When you use `getApplicationContext()` it tends to use a different style and made my spinner have white text on a white background. Hopefully this helps someone else who had the same troubles as me.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I did, it's the pastebin link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's because [`Runnable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) doesn't have a `getActivity()` method.

You can get a reference to the wrapping activity by replacing

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
```

by

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
```

or, because you just need any `Context`

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
```

which is equivalent to

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
```